# Syntax Error with Expectation over Distribution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

I am getting some errors when I try to execute the following code.

Here, the expectation is taken over $g$ which has Nakagami Distribution.

```
s=m*\[Theta]*r^\[Alpha]/(\[Omega]*P);

Exp[-Expectation[Assuming[{P>0,r>0,\[Alpha]>0,\[Lambda]>0,b>0,d>0,m>=0,\[Omega]>0,\[Theta]>0,{P,r,\[Alpha],d,m,\[Omega],\[Theta]}\[Element] Reals},Integrate[(1-Exp[-s*P*g*r^-\[Alpha]])*\[Lambda]*b*d*r^(d-1),{r,a,Infinity}],g\[Distributed]NakagamiDistribution[m,\[Omega]]]]]
```

What went wrong here?

Comment: Look at the error messages:  "Assuming called with 3 arguments; 2 arguments are expected." and "Expectation called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected." mean that you have some misplaced brackets

Comment: This doesn't give an error message, but it's unable to find a numeric value for your expectation value, `Exp[-Expectation[
   Integrate[(1 - Exp[-s*P*g*r^-α])*λ*b*d*
     r^(d - 1), {r, a, Infinity}], 
   g \[Distributed] NakagamiDistribution[m, ω], 
   Assumptions -> {P > 0, r > 0, α > 0, λ > 0, b > 0, 
     d > 0, m >= 0, ω > 0, θ > 
      0, {P, r, α, d, m, ω, θ} ∈ 
      Reals}]]`